# How to obtain the type of a chart in a powerpoint file via POI?

Tags: apache-poi

Powerpoint allows a user to change chart type, like so

[image]

I would like to be able to identify a chart type programetically with the help of Apache POI.

Here is the logic in jython

```
from java.io import ObjectInputStream, FileInputStream, BufferedInputStream, IOException
from org.apache.poi.xslf.usermodel import XMLSlideShow
from org.apache.poi.sl.extractor import SlideShowExtractor
from com.jcabi.xml import XMLDocument
from org.apache.poi.xslf.usermodel import XSLFChart

from org.apache.poi.openxml4j.exceptions import NotOfficeXmlFileException
from org.apache.poi import EmptyFileException
from org.apache.poi.ooxml import POIXMLException


def extract_table(ppt):
    ps = ppt.getSlides()
    tables = []
    for pn, p in enumerate(ps):
        for shape in p.getRelations():
            if type(shape) == XSLFChart:
                ctchart = shape.getCTChart()
                print ctchart.type

def get_slide_file_obj(fn):
    ffn = os.path.abspath(fn)
    fis = FileInputStream(ffn)
    return XMLSlideShow(fis)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    ppt = get_slide_file_obj("/myproject/test.ppts")
    extract_table(ppt)
```

I was hoping the line `print ctchart.type` can print out the chart type.

However the type is `T=CT_Chart@http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/chart` for all different charts in a powerpoint.

How can I get a type name of a chart e.g. `Pie` or `Line`?

Comment: There can be more than one chart in plot area of a `CTChart`. So there cannot be a get-chart-type-method which gets **one** chart-type. `CTChart` has `getPlotArea()` method which gets `CTPlotArea`. And `CTPlotArea` has diverse `sizeOf*ChartArray()` methods, for ex. `sizeOfLineChartArray()`, `sizeOfPieChartArray()`, `sizeOfBarChartArray()`, ... If `CTPlotArea.sizeOfPieChartArray()` returns a `int` greater than 0, then there is a pie chart in the plot area.

Comment: It is a great explanation. Please turn it into an answer and i will upvote & accept.

Comment: For me, this is not an answer. My answers are all tested and contain complete working examples. Glad if you can create a method which consumes a `CTChart` and returns a list of chart-type-names using my hints. Then answer your own question and  provide that method together with a short description what it does.